# apps choice when sharing files

Tags: android

When sharing a file (text file in this case), is it possible to specify an attribute that limits the number of apps to select?
    For example, I run an ACTION_SEND by Intent to share a text file through FileProvider interposed. Android then proposes 10 or 12 apps, whereas only one or two manage to exploit the text file: Gmail, to send an email, X-plore or Total Commander to copy it, but not Chomp to send an sms with attachment, nor such or such notepad...
For example we would need an attribute type: "mail" + "storage" and what else!?

My code, to illustrate and that works well on an external file:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
File.separator + filepath, filename);
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("text/*");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {" "});
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, »Bla « bla bla);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"[" + 
file.getName() + "]");
Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this                                      
              , getString(R.string.fileProvAuthorities)
              , file);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "To share"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing like that. But you could create your own chooser showing only the apps you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily via [Flipboard BottomSheet library](https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet)

Here is a sample:

First, create a string array includes the **package names** of apps to be shared with, into your **strings.xml** file like that:

```
<string-array name="share_apps">
    <item>com.facebook.katana</item>
    <item>com.facebook.orca</item>
    <item>com.twitter.android</item>
    <item>com.whatsapp</item>
    <item>com.google.android.apps.messaging</item>
    <item>com.google.android.talk</item>
    <item>com.google.android.gm</item>
    <item>com.google.android.apps.plus</item>
    <item>com.pinterest</item>
    <item>com.instagram.android</item>
    <item>com.android.email</item>
    <item>com.microsoft.office.outlook</item>
    <item>com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail</item>
    <item>ru.yandex.mail</item>
</string-array>
```

You can add or remove whatever you want in the list. Then, you can use the bottomsheet like below

```
IntentPickerSheetView intentPickerSheet = new IntentPickerSheetView(MainActivity.this, shareIntent, "Share with...", new IntentPickerSheetView.OnIntentPickedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onIntentPicked(IntentPickerSheetView.ActivityInfo activityInfo) {
        bottomSheet.dismissSheet();
        startActivity(activityInfo.getConcreteIntent(shareIntent));
    }
});
// Filter out built in sharing options such as bluetooth and beam.
intentPickerSheet.setFilter(new IntentPickerSheetView.Filter() {
    @Override
    public boolean include(IntentPickerSheetView.ActivityInfo info) {
        String packageName = info.componentName.getPackageName();
        ArrayList<String> apps = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.share_apps)));
        return apps.contains(new String(packageName));
    }
});
// Sort activities in reverse order for no good reason
intentPickerSheet.setSortMethod(new Comparator<IntentPickerSheetView.ActivityInfo>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(IntentPickerSheetView.ActivityInfo lhs, IntentPickerSheetView.ActivityInfo rhs) {
        return rhs.label.compareTo(lhs.label);
    }
});
bottomSheet.showWithSheetView(intentPickerSheet);
```

Comment: Yes, it is interesting, but I'm talking about "types" of apps, not pre-determined apps. Like a type "mail", a type "explorer", etc..